# Fill in your application up to 7 days prior to your arrival

Tags: time, future

I found this sentence in an government-provided online form to visit a country in the Caribbean:

> "You can fill in your Online ED Card application up to 7 days prior to your arrival"

It turns out that I cannot fill "in" (not out?) this form today, 12 days prior to my arrival. I can however, choose a date earlier than my actual arrival, and the form will allow me to proceed.
Am I being dense, thinking that **up to 7 days prior to my arrival** means I can no longer fill this form out getting closer than 7 days to my arrival date?

For example, suppose I will arrive on the 10th, can I fill out this form **from today until the 3rd, but no later?** Or does the sentence imply that I can *only* fill out this form from the 3rd **up until the 10th**?

Comment: This appears to be [Aruba](https://edcardaruba.aw/Application/StepOneNonResident). It looks like you have answered your own question by trying various arrival dates: "Up to 7 days before" means "1, 2...6 or 7 days before".

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit ambiguous but, given that the system would not allow you to complete the form 12 days before your planned arrival, the 7 day period is obviously a maximum rather than a minimum. The system will allow you to complete the form so long as the lead time is seven days or less. You can complete it six days in advance but not 8 days in advance.

The reason for "fill in" rather than "fill out" is probably that the country is a former British colony and, therefore, uses British English. We 'fill in' forms, we don't "fill out" forms. To us forms are completed by inserting characters into boxes so we "fill them in". I don't understand the logic of "filling out" a form at all.